# Gitosis post-update wont run

Tags: git, gitosis

Im running cygwin on a windows vista pc. Ive successfully installed sshd, configured, and built gitosis.
I can remotely git clone the gitosis-admin.git repository, made a change to the config, committed and pushed back to cygwin machine successfully.

However the post-update doesnt execute and the new repository (as specified in the config) have not created.

I have run:

```
chmod 755 /home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update
```

and an ls -l shows the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 git None   69 2010-04-13 22:55 post-update
```

yet, when I run:

```
./post-update
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:gitosis.run_hook:Must have GIT_DIR set in enviroment
```

Ive included in my git .bashrc the line:

```
GIT_DIR=$HOME/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
```

and if I type Set at the prompt, I can see:

```
GIT_DIR=/home/git/repositories/gitosis-admin.git/
```

What else can I try, because Im running out of ideas.

Comment: I haven't used cygwin in years, so I forget -- does it import environment properties from Windows as well? You could try setting the property in Windows.

Comment: Same problem here. @Andy have you any news about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't set `GIT_DIR` -- it shouldn't be necessary.

Secondly, I believe your issue is that you have added write permission for a new repo to your Gitosis config, but it's not being created when you push your config. That's because adding a new repo to your Gitosis config doesn't *create* it -- it just gives a user *permission* to create it.

For example, let's say you add this go your Gitosis config:

```
[group new_repo]
    members = me
    writable = new_repo
```

When you push the changes out, `new_repo` does not get created -- you merely have permission to create it. In order to actually create it on the server, create the repo on your local machine, and then add your Gitosis server as a remote:

```
$ git remote add gitosis git@git.example.com:new_repo.git
```

And then push it out:

```
$ git push gitosis master
```

The new repo will be created when you do the `git push`.

Comment: I tried committing a new_repo project, that failed too. only one response, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. Interestingly I logged into the cygwin bash, manually created a new_repo git project under repositories folder. And that I cannot clone either. Yet getting gitosis-admin.git bares no problem.

Comment: @Andy, hello, have you fixed the problem?